# How does Google Search access my Facebook connections?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search-engine, google-plus

When I am logged into my Google account and I search anything on Google,
these days if it is a blog or a profile, Google shows the name of the owner. and also tells me if I am connected to that person.

I can understand if Its a blogger blog where the author might be having a Google+ account which I am connected to.

But under my Facebook friends account in Google search results.
It reads "You are connected to XYZ on Facebook" on hovering over is name.

Is it because I told Google Plus about my other profile links, ie Twitter and Facebook ?

I don't think connections are accessible under Graph API without any access token and I don't remember giving Google any such permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google dashboard at https://www.google.com/dashboard list what Google knows about you, under the section "Me on the Web" I believe you can adjust what twitter/Facebook profiles are linked to you Google account. I don't have any so I'm not %100 sure but a good place to check.

Comment: Yes,This definitely answers my question to a certain extent.
Since I ahve provided links to my tumblr, twitter and Facebook profile to Google. It can know who Iam.
But then again , how will it know, who my friends are ?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely due to your logged in facebook session. If this is active, it will show up on websites allowing you to comment on certain things, from the random website, straight onto facebook. Or like it, etc etc.

Google is most likely just using your logged in session.

If you dont like such features (I personally hate facebook apps on websites ), you can block them using script blocking addons for your browser.

I.e. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/

Comment: It maybe that your facebook login is being cached. Try cleaning cookies etc from your browser and see if the problem persists. Still, I find it odd that logging out of fb hasnt fixed the problem.